# red screen after second update on a snake game

Tags: javascript

I watched a tutorial about a simple snake game, after putting in the interval to update the canvas (id = "board") the first apple appears, but with the first update the whole background also turns red.
The snake (at this point just a green block) can still move.

I looked into the update function but couldnt find the flaw, I looked at the other stuff but I just cant find it

```js
//board
var blockSize = 25;
var rows = 20;
var cols = 20;
var board;
var context; 

//snake head
var snakeX = blockSize * 5;
var snakeY = blockSize * 5;

var velocityX = 0;
var velocityY = 0;

var foodX;
var foodY;


window.onload = function() {
    board = document.getElementById("board");
    board.height = rows * blockSize;
    board.width = cols * blockSize;
    context = board.getContext("2d"); //used for drawing on the board

    placeFood();
    document.addEventListener("keyup", changeDirection);
    // update();
    setInterval(update, 1000/10);

}

function update() {
    context.filStyle="black";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, board.width, board.height);

    context.fillStyle="lime"
    snakeX += velocityX * blockSize;
    snakeY += velocityY * blockSize;
    context.fillRect (snakeX, snakeY, blockSize, blockSize);

    context.fillStyle="red";
    context.fillRect (foodX, foodY, blockSize, blockSize);
}

function changeDirection(e){
    if (e.code == "ArrowUp") {
        velocityX = 0;
        velocityY = -1;
    }
    else if (e.code == "ArrowDown") {
        velocityX = 0;
        velocityY = 1;
    }
    else if (e.code == "ArrowLeft") {
        velocityX = -1;
        velocityY = 0;
    }
    else if (e.code == "ArrowRight") {
        velocityX = 1;
        velocityY = 0;
    }
}

function placeFood() {

    // Math.random -> 0-1 *cols ? 0-19,9999 -> 0-19 *25 (floor ist runden)
    foodX = Math.floor (Math.random() *cols) *blockSize;
    foodY = Math.floor (Math.random() *rows) *blockSize;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="board"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistake. change `context.filStyle` to `context.fillStyle`. Also, please fix the inconsistency in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I'd missed this - but you should know that questions that are caused by a simple typo should not be answered (a comment explaining the problem to the OP is helpful though), but voted to be closed.

Comment: Ah, I see. I did not know about the rules much, because I'm not very active.